Why do I have to import Truth methods manually? (no auto suggestions even after Gradle sync)
Just installed Truth (actually the truth extensions) using
testImplementation(libs.androidx.truth)

where
[versions]
truthVersion = "1.6.0-beta01"

[libraries]
androidx-truth = { module = "androidx.test.ext:truth", version.ref = "truthVersion" }

Of course I synced in Android Studio.
Now, when I started typing assertTh..., I get no auto completion. I had to add
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.* 

manually to get things (auto completion) working. Why is that?

androidx.test.ext:truth contains AndroidX's extensions to Truth (as you've noted). You might want those, too, but for the classes in com.google.common.truth itself, you'll need com.google.truth:truth.
